# My code for retrieving last tweet date doesn't work properly since yesterday

Tags: javascript, twitter

Before yesterday the following JS code worked fine for retrieving the last tweet and its date :

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/mon_compte_twitter.json?callback=?", function(data) { 

var date = data.created_at;  
var finale = data[i].text;  

var dateTwit = new Date(date);           
var dateAct = new Date();           
var diff = dateAct.getTime() - dateTwit.getTime();
```

Today it works only if the tweet was posted many days ago, but if the last tweet was posted a few minutes or hours ago, its date is negative !!!

Anybody could tell why ?

Answer (score 1):

The URL is wrong. You should use:

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=mon_compte&callback=?", function(data) { ... })
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to the problems that twitter is currently having, my web app has stopped working this morning without any reason.
I think twitters external API is just a bit broken at the moment.